# Binomial coefficient in Java (adapting the following source)

Tags: java

I have 2 parameters and I want the method to return an int result.. I was given this code but I don't understand naff all about binoms etc and don't know how to "convert" it
has `double BC[126][126];` defined somewhere above it. But i don't need that i just want a result for these n and m. (I probably sound like numpty for putting like that)

```
private void binom(int n, int m) {
    int i, j;

    if (n>=0)
        if (m>n||m<0) System.err.println("Illegal m!!\n");

        else { 
            for(i=0;i<=n;i++) BC[i][0] = 1;
            for(i=1;i<=m;i++) BC[0][i] = 0;
            for(j=1;j<=m;j++) for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                BC[i][j] = BC[i-1][j-1] + BC[i-1][j];
        }

    else System.err.println("Negative n!!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just return `BC[n][m]` which is the element you calculate with the three for cycles..

by the way you have at least three possible implementations:

- trivial recursive
- this one (dynamic programming)
- using the formula `n! / (n-m)!m!` which is no good since fact operations are annoying

A correction: your approach would be dynamic programming if you avoid to recalculate all the coefficients everytime the method gets invoked but it is not your case..

Answer (score 2):

See the article [*Computing Binomial Coefficients*](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page460.html) for an example with comparable complexity, *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, but using only *O(n)* space instead of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.